How to extract dynamically changing data in a html of the site
I want to get mine locations in a game the game uses php site and it updates the html dynamically based on user actions for example if I click a tile the game will send a post request to the HTML and the mine locations are only revealed when I cashout or clicked a mine so I want to get the mine locations of real time before I even click any tile tried using Java and Python but they don't extract the mine positions so we need to extract the mine locations tile id in the HTML and simulate click on the tiles to get the desired response but the code should keep up with the game because after I win or lose again the HTML will change so please help me.
I tried using this code but didn't work at all so I need to manipulate the HTML not the network request problem is the HTML changes dynamically.
import requests

import time



def configure_game_params():

    game_params = {

        "access-token": "39fa080b862e50c48c11a5a5f5a8034f53e1f7d76fb9fa5c4675fed1f1f482450c",

        "fp-userSeed": "SnuPVeYLOWKNACMDK12dyoEIooUuXm4iCLSwDprUta3FuRtHST74O3HRrz4qA0J7",

        "gameAccess": "true",

        "isClientSeedSet": "false",  # Set to "true" or "false" as needed

        "user-email": "njongomagagula@gmail.com",

        "mines_bet": "0.00074249",  # Replace with your actual value

        "color-scheme": "dark",

        "selectedCurrency": "DGB",

    }

    return game_params



def construct_request_headers():

    headers = {

        "Content-Type": "application/json",

        "Accept": "application/json",

        "Authorization": "Bearer ae1ece19d806d9e6630429bac2cfb2f4a406b6ddc0a37af0856635880cb73d7e",

    }

    return headers



def make_api_request(url, payload, headers, retries=3):

    for _ in range(retries):

        try:

            response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

            if response.status_code == 200:

                return response

            elif response.status_code == 429:

                print("Rate limit exceeded. Retrying after backoff.")

                time.sleep(2 ** _)

            else:

                print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

        except requests.RequestException as e:

            print(f"Error: {e}")

    return None



# Configure game parameters

game_params = configure_game_params()



# Construct the request headers

headers = construct_request_headers()



# Mock the "busted" status in the request payload

request_payload = {

    "status": "BUSTED",

    **game_params,

}



# Make the API request with retries and backoff

response = make_api_request("https://api.faucetpay.io/mines/sweep", request_payload, headers)



# Handle response

if response:

    mine_locations = response.json().get("data", {}).get("mine_locations")

    if mine_locations:

        print("Mine locations:", mine_locations)

    else:

        print("No mine locations found.")

else:

    print("Failed to retrieve mine locations.")


please use punctuation. what doesn't work in your code? it looks like you need javascript

The code fetch mine locations from the api before i play the game the params we set in the code are for making the request to track or configure the exact game i am playing at that time senario so it doesnt work it says sesdion is expired or bad tocken even when the session is not expired in the real game

edit your question to add your session problem errors. you're using requests.post instead of requests.session, it might be a problem

Ive found a new way but it needs knowledge about html hidden classes if that html class can be seen the class show i can see the img in that tile id because the show class has the mine img taged along it depending if it a crystal so now i need a way to view the html deeper and reveal hidden clases can you help there
